# Yii2 save upload image in folder

Tags: php, yii2

My upload image root directory get like this:-

```
Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = realpath(Yii::$app->basePath) . '/web/uploads/';

D:\wamp\www\yii2\frontend/web/uploads/imagename.
```

How to change it??

Use also like this
Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl().'/frontend/web/uploads/';

Get the correct path but image can't move the upload folder

Answer (score 0):

You need URL management and not path management
Try this

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
Url::to(['/uploads/']);
```

Comment: Use this code get the correct url but image not save in uploads folder

Comment: You asked for the corretct path if you think this is useful please rate the answer. For the save of image  chcek if the saveAs return true or not  if return not see this for errore explanation  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Try all above coding in my controller but image not save in folder . Please any one help me

Comment: Maybe to big ?  UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE

    Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

In controller you can try this:

```
$fileupload = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
          if(!empty($fileupload)){
              $fileupload->saveAs('uploads/' . $fileupload->baseName . '.' . $fileupload->extension);
          }
```

and in the form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>
```

the code inside the activeform::begin() is very important to move the image inside the desired folder.
It has worked for me. Hope it will work for you too.

Comment: Then take a new variable instead of file in your form and declare it in your model.

<?= $form->field($model, 'new_variable')->fileInput() ?>
By doing this controller first search this in your database table and if it is not found then it search the variable declaration in your model.
and until you do not pass this variable to your database field, it will not be saved in your databse but it will transfer to the desired folder.

Comment: Second thing you can do is that in controller do not save the model and until you do not save the model, details will not be saved in the databse.

Comment: After uploading the file and submit the form the following error will be displayed                        Error (#2)
An internal server error occurred.

Comment: Can you provide your code what exactly are you trying so that i can take a look ?